# Notation to refer to all the n element subsets of a set?

Tags: reference-request, notation

Is there a notation to refer to all the n element subsets of a set? I know the power set denotes all of the subsets.

Comment: Some people use ${S}\choose{n}$, confer [an answer on mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/a/42992/26710) on suggestions for good notation.

Comment: That's very nonstandard. I'd go about defining a notation for it, such as
$$\mathcal P_n (A) := \{O\in\mathcal P(A) | \#(O) = n\}$$
Where $\#$ denotes the number of elements.

Comment: I see $[A]^n$ ocasionally.

Comment: @AlexR: ${S}\choose{n}$ is completely standard in combinatorics.

Comment: @HansLundmark seeing your reference, I agree (an upvoted mo post seems legitimate ;) ). Forgive my unawareness.